# Kafka reads messages from a topic which was revoked

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a problem with consumer group.
Several consumers read the topic, then another consumer is added in the same group and group is rebalancing.

Revoke previously assigned partitions partition-4, partition-6, partition-5, partition-7

Adding newly assigned partitions: partition-8, partition-7, partition-9

After rebalance the new consumer reads the partitions: partition-8, partition-7, partition-9
And at the same time, for a minute, these partitions continue to be read by the consumer to whom these partitions were previously assigned
Why does the consumer continue to read partitions that have been revoked ?

Comment: are all consumers (old and new) from same consumer group?

Comment: yes, they are all in one consumer group